# Authenticate to use Google Sheets with service account instead of personal account in C# .NET

Tags: c#, json, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I have an application that I developed that utilizes a few Google Sheets.

I was able to figure out how to get it to have access to the Google Sheets API using the following code:

```
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream =
                  new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }
    // Create Google Sheets API service.
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
```

This application will be used by a few other people - but the first time they run the application it asks them to login to Google - but their accounts don't give them the appropriate access.

I think (correct me if I'm wrong) - using a Service Account should resolve my issue and no longer prompt a user to 'login', but still allow my application to read/update the Sheets appropriately.

I'd like to take my existing code and modify it to use a Service Account but I can't find any good documentation on how to do that. I have created the Service Account and have the ServiceAccount.json file in the same spot as the current 'client_secret.json' file but am unsure how to proceed much further.

I have tried changing the code to:

```
    ServiceAccountCredential credential;
    //UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("HelperServiceAccount.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            )
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }
    // Create Google Sheets API service.
    var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
```

But it fails - the credential variable gives an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to check the document about [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), this explain how to properly authorize a service account to access the Google Sheet API. There is a [sample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) from nodejs that it is possible to use service account to access Sheets API.

Comment: Lastly, try reading [Using Google's Spreadsheet API using .NET, OAuth 2.0 and a Service Account](https://markembling.info/2012/12/google-spreadsheet-dotnet-oauth2-service-account), which will help you understand code implementation for c#. Hoep this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think I stumbled across that site in some of my travels around the web, although it deals with p12 files and I'm working with a .json file specifically. I think I'm almost there though - I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

You should have created the service account and stored the json credential file:

Then try this:

```
        ServiceAccountCredential credential;
        string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
        string jsonfile = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.json";
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@jsonfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = (ServiceAccountCredential)
                GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).UnderlyingCredential;

            var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credential.Id)
            {
                User = serviceAccountEmail,
                Key = credential.Key,
                Scopes = Scopes
            };
            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. It doesn't look like the cleanest (official) pattern, but it gives correct results. I would have expected the Google Sheets API to provide a simple method to create the ServiceAccountCredential from a stream directly in one call like with the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest code:

```
var credential = (ServiceAccountCredential)GoogleCredential
    .FromFile("client_secret.json")
    .CreateScoped(SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets)
    .UnderlyingCredential;

var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = AppName,
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I've made this project to allow users to create service accounts credentials using both json or p12 credential files. And if you want to access user data from your domain, be sure to enable the wide domain delegation option before.

[GoogleApiServiceFactory](https://github.com/drodriguesaar/GoogleApiServiceFactory)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)