# C# Error when using Google Sheets API with service account

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use my service account to work with Google Sheets API inside my .net 5 app. I started with ["quickstart" example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) and it works fine. But I need to put my app inside docker container, so authorization from "quickstart" that uses browser doesn't fit me.
I decided to try to authorize with google service account. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48667099/9284176) but when I am trying to execute any request it throws error `'Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT Signature.", Uri:""'`

Here's my code for credentials setup:

```
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;

namespace GoogleSheetsParser.Helpers
{
    public class GoogleSheetsServiceSettings
    {
        private static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };

        public static ServiceAccountCredential Credential { get; private set; }

        public static void Setup()
        {
            var serviceAccountEmail = "my@seviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
            using Stream stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            var credential = (ServiceAccountCredential)
                GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).UnderlyingCredential;

            var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(credential.Id)
            {
                User = serviceAccountEmail,
                Key = credential.Key,
                Scopes = Scopes
            };
            Credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Startup.cs

```
namespace GoogleSheetsParser
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

            GoogleSheetsServiceSettings.Setup();
            var sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApplicationName"),
                HttpClientInitializer = GoogleSheetsServiceSettings.Credential
            });
            
            services.AddSingleton(sheetsService);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's usage of configured sheets service:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using GoogleSheetsParser.Dto;

namespace GoogleSheetsParser.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SheetsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private SheetsService SheetsService { get; }

        public SheetsController(SheetsService sheetsService)
        {
            SheetsService = sheetsService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetSheets([FromQuery] GetSheetsRequestDto dto)
        { 
            var spreadsheet = SheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(dto.SpreadsheetId).Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it on my local machine in Visual Studio project.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is code posted the working code?

Comment: It compiles, if you're asking about that :) Why are you asking?

Comment: It is not clear if the posted code is the working or non working code and what is the differences between working and non working.

Comment: Well when I'am setting up my credentials this way - any request fails with error. I don't think that I need to show working code from example because it's completely different.

Comment: I would highly suggest.  add in "using" statements.  and also suggest getting rid of "var" of posting of questions.  the combination of missing using statements and "var" overload....very difficult for a reader to know what those objects are.

Comment: How old is the Google API?  Are you using HTTPS (secure)?  Issues like this often are attributed to the TLS version that is being used to do authentication.  TLS 1.0 and 1.1 was disabled and not you must use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  Older API are using 1.0 or 1.1.  If it is a TLS issue there are lots of reasons and fixes.

Comment: @jdweng It's latest API. Get it from nuget.
Didn't get about HTTPS using. Using for what?

Comment: You are sending a request which can be either non secure HTTP or secure HTTPS.  HTTPS does TLS for authentication to encrypt.  Old sample code may not work if it was written form HTTP.  The quick start page is 2021 which should be good.  You should read the links at bottom of the page.  I think you need to work with TLS 1.3 which means you cannot use Net and need to use Operating System https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/tls-1-3-is-now-on-by-default-for-google-cloud-services?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am not sending requests as you can see from my code. Google libs do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear to me why it's using a JWT here at all, but you can definitely avoid going quite as low-level, using `GoogleCredential.CreateWithUser` and `GoogleCredential.CreateScoped`. Here's the code I'd write in your `Setup`:

```cs
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;

namespace GoogleSheetsParser.Helpers
{
    public class GoogleSheetsServiceSettings
    {
        public static GoogleCredential Credential { get; private set; }

        public static void Setup() =>
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credentials.json")
                .CreateScoped(SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets)
                .CreateWithUser("my@seviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
    }
}
```

It's not clear why you'd set the user to a different service account though - normally you use `CreateWithUser` to impersonate a *regular* user with a service account. If you want to act as a service account, just generate a JSON file with credentials for that service account, and don't bother with impersonation.

Comment: Works just fine for me!